# Why can't the linker find main()?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, ld

I'm getting the next error message:

> ```
> usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In
> function `_start':  (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main' 
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

The only code I have is:

```
FILE *f = fopen("data/file.dat", "rb");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
long pos = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

char *bytes = malloc(pos);
fread(bytes, pos, 1, f);
fclose(f);
```

Now, I come from a Java background but I've been Googling around, it says I might be missing a reference but I don't know what could it be, I even added the `#include <stdio.h>` and I read something about adding an `extern` but I have no idea where since I have no other files unless I need to refer to the .dat file?

**EDIT** I also tried in a point to cast the byte array `(char*)malloc(pos);` but it didn't help either.

**EDIT 2**
the whole code is using the NS-3 framework but everything compiled perfectly until I added these lines. It looks something like this:

```
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"
#include "ns3/wifi-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/csma-module.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"

using namespace ns3;

NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("ThirdScriptExample");

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
      .....
//STARTS FILE READING
  FILE *f = fopen("data/Terse_Jurassic_10_14_18.dat", "rb");
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
  long pos = ftell(f);
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

  char *bytes = (char*)malloc(pos);
  fread(bytes, pos, 1, f);
  fclose(f);

  Simulator::Stop (Seconds (10.0));

  pointToPoint.EnablePcapAll ("third");
  phy.EnablePcap ("third", apDevices.Get (0));
  csma.EnablePcap ("third", csmaDevices.Get (0), true);

  Simulator::Run ();
  Simulator::Destroy ();
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler error message is:

> ```
> [1888/1930] cxxprogram:  -> build/scratch/data/data
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In
> function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status Build failed  -> task in 'data'
> failed (exit status 1):   {task 43470800: cxxprogram  -> data}
> ```

I am extremely sure the NS-3 code (both the part I didn't add due to code lines and the the one after reading the file works because before adding the part to read the file everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Is your code within a int main () {...}  function?

Comment: Do you have a `main` in your code? Something like `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or something similar. You can compile a program without a `main` but you cannot `link` it.

Comment: yes an `int main (int argc, char *argv[]){}`

Comment: Show us all the code — and also show us the compilation statement (e.g. `gcc -Wall foo.c -o foo`).

Comment: Is it in the same file as the above code or in a different file?

Comment: What command do you run to compile/link which gives this error?

Comment: It's a command from NS-3 `./waf --run filename`

Comment: So, the 'only code you have' is not actually the only code you have.  In fact, there's still a pile of code not revealed, masked as five dots.  However, you're correct; normally, that shouldn't matter.  The problem appears to be that the compiler is not compiling your code since your code defines `main()` and the code that the compiler is trying to compile does not.  The fact that you're not using a normal compiler command doesn't help.  Where is this 'NS-3' stuff from?  Have you looked at its manual and samples?  What do they do that's different?

Comment: yes, I went over the entire tutorial. It's a network simulator and basically what I'm trying to add over it is to read a file to simulate the transfer of a video between devices but I can't seem to read the files

Comment: Is this the NS-3 from http://www.nsnam.org/?

Comment: Maybe show all the output from the `waf` program. Also let us know what the name of the file is that has your `main()`.  Is that file in the current directory when you run `./waf --run filename`?

Comment: my file is called wifiSim.cc and yes it's in the directory when I run as for the output, right now it's the error

Answer (score 0):

> The only code I have is

Eiher you didn't put this code into `main` function (which you are required to have), or your compiler/linker invocation is incorrect.  It's impossible to say which, given the details you've supplied.

Also, your question has incorrect title: you don't have a problem reading a file, you have a problem *linking* your program (that intends to read a file).

Answer (score 0):

Your program *must* contain one `main()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f = fopen("data/file.dat", "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long pos = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *bytes = malloc(pos);
    fread(bytes, pos, 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    free(bytes);
    return 0;
}
```